# I have created a aws private api gateway, but don't know where to find the public dns name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, api-gateway

I have created a private aws api gateway with a test method. Per this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) I can call it by using the public dns name. Anyone knows where I can find the public dns name of my api. I only can see ARN name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. the dns is in the endpoint configuration. I have to created a new endpoint of executeapi service in vpc service. I can choose enable private dns or not during the creation.